# Launch another app intent from last open activity (resume)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I use the following code to launch other apps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, activity));
intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This works however it makes the launched app start from the beginning, not from the last opened activity (resuming it). Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Dont you think its behaving properly since you are starting `activity` with `launcher` by adding this line `intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);`

Comment: In intent try to give the other apps fully qualified class name. intent.setClassName("App-A activity name from where you launch the app-B","App-B activity name with package name")

Answer (score 1):

Use a "launch `Intent`", like this:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startActivity(intent);
```

This `Intent` has all the necessary flags and settings to bring an existig task to the foreground or to start a new one (if the app is not running).